# Find Last Day of Last Year in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I know how to find this (current) year's last day in MySQL.

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH)); //It shows this year (2017)'s last day. ==> 2017-12-31
```

But I do not know how to find LAST YEAR's Last Day.

What queries should I enter to determine last year last day?

For example:

```
++++This Year++++ | ++++Last Year's Last Day++++

   2017           |        2016-12-31
   2018           |        2017-12-31
   2019           |        2018-12-31
   2020           |        2019-12-31
```

Thanks for your help,
much appreciated.

Comment: I'm as big a fan or mysql data functions as anyone, but you do realize that December 31 is the last day of every year...

Comment: Or rather that January 1st is the first day of every year. In consequence, I think you've accepted the poorer answer.

Comment: To be fair, the answer was accepted before I even posted mine.  I didn't have time to answer right away so by the time I got around it it, it was already there.  I think Gordon's answer is fine, and in many circumstances, a similar approach is the best way to handle it, as in finding "last monday" or questions of that nature.  People in the future who may find this will have both approaches to ponder, so I think this SO question will be a good resource in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subtract one year:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 12-MONTH(NOW()) MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks mate! I will accept your answer since the system doesn't allow me to accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, in this particular case, where the last day of the year (or the first) never ever changes, you can go with a much simpler solution.

There are actually quite a few ways to do this, and in this case without making it into a datetime as Gordon did and using DATE_ADD with negative intervals.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-12-31');

+------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-12-31') |
+------------------------------------+
| 2016-12-31                         |
+------------------------------------+
```

Probably in most situations just getting that as a string in standard MySQL date format is fine, but if you actually need it to be a mysql date for comparison purposes or because the mysql client is reading the mysql datatype and doing something special with that in your serverside language, then you can convert that using STR_TO_DATE.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-12-31'), '%Y-%m-%d');
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-12-31'), '%Y-%m-%d') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-12-31                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```